# loop over file and get file size of url request - python

Tags: python, loops, file, url, size

i am trying to run a simple loop over a .txt file that contains a number of url download requests for files.  ultimately, i am after knowing the file size of these url requests.

when i execute the code below, they read as 0.00 MB but if i run the code directly with the url it returns the correct file size.  Not sure what is going on.

```
import requests

with open("textDB2021.txt") as f:
   for url in f:
       # pass URL as first argument
       response = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True)
       size = response.headers.get('content-length', -1)
       # size in megabytes (Python 2, 3)
       print('{:<40}: {:.2f} MB'.format('FILE SIZE', int(size) / float(1 << 20)))
```

Output:

```
FILE SIZE                               : 0.00 MB
FILE SIZE                               : 0.00 MB
FILE SIZE                               : 0.00 MB
```

Comment: can you print the value of `size`? just do `print(size)` and put the result

Comment: printing just the size still results in a very small file.  it should be in the MB range.

Comment: yes, but it confirms that size is not 0. so the error is in your conversion to MB. are you sure the conversion to MB is dividing by 2^20?

Comment: yes, regardless of the conversion it is still incorrect.  If i remove url from the requests.head and put in the url directly i get the file size i am expecting.

it only fails when i try to loop in the txt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError
import math


def convert_size(size_bytes: int) -> str:
    """
    :param size_bytes:
    :return:
    get size in bytes and return string e.g. '241.19 MB'
    """
    if size_bytes == 0:
        return "0B"
    size_name = ("B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB")
    i = int(math.floor(math.log(size_bytes, 1024)))
    p = math.pow(1024, i)
    s = round(size_bytes / p, 2)
    return "%s %s" % (s, size_name[i])


def get_file_size_by_url(url: str) -> str:
    try:
        obj_info = urlopen(url)
        size_int = int(obj_info.getheader('Content-Length'))
        size_pretty = convert_size(size_bytes=size_int)
    except URLError as e:
        print('with file {} error: {}'.format(url, e))
        size_pretty = 'N/A'
    return size_pretty


def check_sizes(urls: list) -> None:
    for url in urls:
        url_file = url.split('/')[-1]
        s = get_file_size_by_url(url=url)
        print('file {} size is {}'.format(url_file, s))
    return


def main() -> None:
    urls = [
        'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/logo.png',
        'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8d/Google_logo_%282010-2013%29.svg',
        'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b3/Wikipedia-logo-v2-en.svg',
        'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/NoSuchFile.png'
    ]
    check_sizes(urls=urls)
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\GiladEiniKbyLake\.conda\envs\wu\python.exe D:/workspace/2021wizzi_utils/temp/url.py
file logo.png size is 5.93 KB
file Google_logo_%282010-2013%29.svg size is 44.24 KB
file Wikipedia-logo-v2-en.svg size is 202.96 KB
with file https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/NoSuchFile.png error: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
file NoSuchFile.png size is N/A
```